# Best approach for Nested UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have two `viewControllers` for iPad just like facebook sidepanel. There is `LeftViewController` which toggles when I click a button on center `viewController`. It slides on the top of `CenterViewController`. But it covers only 50% of `centerViewController`.

I should be able to add new views to left `viewController` and can push.

What is the best approach to achieve this.

Comment: I can't understand,are you asked Slide Sidebar(slide out or in)?

Comment: yes. i have slide side bar in which i should be able to push and pop between views.

Comment: Are you looking for a drawer controller with sidebar menu ?? as like this link https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mmdrawercontroller--2

Comment: yes. something like this. There is some more customization needed. Also i need it in swift. i couldn't find any. so i thought of implementing own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this link

[Sliding Drawers](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=drawer)

[[SideMenus]](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/tags/sidebar)

This contains different drawers and few in swift too. may be this link would be helpful to you.

Comment: yes @kampai but if any user want to know some better library then as the answer link to the thing which is helpful to the user should be there. we could set link to the git or any repository here so we can give link as answer too. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can add slide-in side bar in view.see below my code.

assign the property in .h file

```
 UIView*menuDrawer;

@property(readonly,nonatomic)UISwipeGestureRecognizer*recognizer_open,*recognizer_close;
@property(readonly,nonatomic) int menuDrawerX,menuDrawerWidth;
```

//customize slide menu

Add this code in viewdidload

```
 int statusBarHeight=[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height-20;
    menuDrawerWidth=self.view.frame.size.width*0.65;//you can adjust width
    menuDrawerX=self.view.frame.origin.x-menuDrawerWidth;
    menuDrawer=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(menuDrawerX, self.view.frame.origin.y+statusBarHeight, menuDrawerWidth,self.view.frame.size.height-statusBarHeight)];
    menuDrawer.backgroundColor=[UIColor
                                whiteColor];
    recognizer_close=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipes:)];
    recognizer_open=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipes:)];
    recognizer_close.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    recognizer_open.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;


    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer_close];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer_open];
    [self.view addSubview:menuDrawer];
```

add this method

```
-(void)handleSwipes:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    [self drawerAnimation];

}
```

call this method,if you are assigning a button also can set selector of a button

```
-(void)drawerAnimation
{

 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:-5];

    CGFloat new_x = 0;
    if (menuDrawer.frame.origin.x < self.view.frame.origin.x) {
        new_x=menuDrawer.frame.origin.x + menuDrawerWidth;
        }
    else
    {
        new_x=menuDrawer.frame.origin.x - menuDrawerWidth;
    }
    menuDrawer.frame=CGRectMake(new_x, menuDrawer.frame.origin.y, menuDrawer.frame.size.width, menuDrawer.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];


}
```

it will work fine,you can add UITableView or other controls in these slide-in side bar menu.

you can adjust height and width via statusBarHeight and menuDrawerWidth.